# Error de Memoria Jupyter Nootebook pandas - numpy

Tags: python, numpy, jupyter

Hola a todas las personas de la comunidad, soy principiante en el tema de python,especialmente manejando las librerías de análisis de datos. Me encontraba manipulando un dataframe, trabajando con las librerías pandas, numpy, sns, y matplotlib, y cuando hice una operación me salio el siguiente error, el cual no entiendo. Si alguien pudiera explicarme estaría agradecido. Muchas gracias.

> MemoryError: Unable to allocate 19.4 TiB for an array with shape
> (2659620087709,) and data type float64

Comment: 19.4 TiB es mucha información. No conozco una computadora que tenga 20TiB en RAM (las computadoras actuales comúnes están aún en los GiB). Te recomiendo leer respecto a los prefijos griegos (o más bien los ISO/IEC) en este enlace de [wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte#M%C3%BAltiplos_utilizando_los_prefijos_ISO/IEC_80000-13). Usa cómputo distribuido o batch processing.

Comment: El error dice: "Error de Memoria: No se hay 19.4 TiB (terabytes) disponibles para un arreglo de dimensión 2.659.620.087.709". Revisa tu código.